# What is the initial algebra of the identity functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am trying to solve some of the exercises in Bird's *Algebra of Programming*. He defines an initial algebra as the initial object in the category of some [F-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Algebra#Definition).

In the book, he says that

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

is the initial algebra of the `Maybe` Functor, i.e, the functor F, where  $FA = 1 + A$ and $Ff = id_1 + f$.

Then he asks the following question as an exercise:

> What is the initial algebra of the Identity Functor?

I have two guesses for this:

- My first guess, going by the pattern indicated for Nat, would be some bizzare object like this: `data X = Tag X`. But in this case, I cannot figure out what the homomorphism from `X` to an arbitrary `A` be.
- My second guess is that the initial object is some kind of tagged union of all the types and the homomorphism is an appropriate projection.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It seems that your wikipedia link does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** copy-paste the sections in this answer to play with inside `ghci`

Note that the initial object can be represented in Haskell as as an inhabitant of the type `Mu` (as shown below).

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
import Prelude hiding (Maybe, Just, Nothing)

-- | Mu F = initial object with respect to functor F
data Mu f = Mu (f (Mu f))
```

I now  exhibit the ismorphism  between `Nat` and `Mu Maybe` below:

```
-- | Maybe
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing deriving(Show)

-- | Naturals
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving(Show)

-- | Bijection between naturals and initial object of Maybe functor
natfwd :: Nat -> Mu (Maybe)
natfwd Zero = Mu Nothing
natfwd (Succ n) = Mu (Just (natfwd n))

natbwd :: Mu (Maybe) -> Nat
natbwd (Mu Nothing) =  Zero
natbwd (Mu (Just mu)) = Succ (natbwd mu)
```

Next, I show that the initial object generated by `Id` is isomorphic to `Void` --- that is, it is uninhabited.

Intuitively, the initial object contains "arbitrary many nestings" of the original functor `F`. In the `Maybe` case, we had the ability to use `Nothing` to terminate this nesting. However, in the case of `Id`, this is no longer the case: there is no "branch" in the type `Id` to break this arbitrary recursion. Hence, it cannot be inhabited by any inductive value.

`Void` is a way to declare values in haskell that cannot be inhabited, in case you have not seen it before. `Void` has no data constructors.

```
data Void

data Id a = Id a

isoFwd :: Mu Id -> Void
isoFwd (Mu (Id x)) = isoFwd x

isoBwd :: Void -> Mu Id
isoBwd v = case v of
```

#### Claim: `isoFwd : Mu Id -> Void` proves that `Mu Id` is not inhabited

Assume for contradiction that `Mu Id` is inhabited. Hence, there exists an `x : Mu Id`. Now, compute `y = (isoFwd x) : Void`. But we know that `Void` is uninhabited. Hence, contradiction. Therefore, `Mu Id` must be uninhabited.

#### Claim: `isoFwd, isoBwd` define an isomorphism between `Void` and `Mu Id`

To discuss equality of functions, we define:
\begin{align*}
\forall f, g : X \rightarrow Y, \quad
f ~\texttt{==}~g \equiv \forall x \in X, f (x) = g(x)
\end{align*}

Note that if $X$ is uninhabited, then the relation ${f~\texttt{==}~g}$ is vacuously true. Armed with this, we show that `isoFwd. isoBwd = id = isoBwd . isoFwd`.

- `isoFwd . isoBwd :: Void -> Void == id :: Void -> Void` since `Void` is uninhabited, and hence the two LHS and RHS are vacuously equal.
- `isoBwd . isoFwd :: Mu Id -> Mu Id == id :: Mu Id -> Mu Id` since `Mu Id`
  is uninhabited, and hence the LHS and RHS are vacuously equal.

#### Further reading

For more of this kind of computational perspective, I can recommend reading about recursion schemes and cata/anamorphisms, from [Bananas, Lenses, and Barbed Wire](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf) as well as the [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library.

Comment: Why is `isoFwd . isoBwd = id = isoBwd . isoFwd`, though?

Comment: I don't know of a "formal" answer, except to notice that `isoFwd :: Mu Id -> Void` gives us immediate proof that `Mu Id` is uninhabited. `Void` is another type that is uninhabited, and hence are isomorphic.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I wrote down a formal proof of why `isoFwd . isoBwd = id = isoBwd . isoFwd`. Please accept the question if the explanation is satisfactory, and if not, feel free to tell me where it fails :)

Answer (score -1):

The initial algebra of the identity functor is a set $X$ together with a map $X\to X$ that is initial among all such maps : for any set $Y$ and map $Y\to Y$, there is a unique map $X\to Y$ making

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} X @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
Y@>>> Y\end{CD}$$commute. In particular, for any $Y$ there is a unique map $X\to Y$ (taking $id_Y :Y\to Y$), so $X$ is initial.

Conversely, if $X$ is initial...

Comment: You are technically correct, but unfortunately I am not able to gather any useful realisation other than a restatement of the definition

Comment: I meant initial in the base category, not initial as an algebra. Those are two very different (a priori) properties, my claim is that they are the same. Now initial objects in base categories are often very simple : e.g. in Sets, it's the empty set, etc.

Comment: I see. That makes more sense. thanks